# SimpleDateFormat java giving wrong output

Tags: java, datetime

```
SimpleDateFormat default_date_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
default_date_formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(default_date_formatter.parse("2010-01-01T00:43:54.776000"));
```

gives `Thu Dec 31 16:56:50 PST 2009` as the result instead of `Thu Dec 31 16:43:54 PST 2009`

The times are off `16:56:50 v/s 16:43:54`

Comment: You should include the code which actually prints the `Thu Dec 31` timestamp to the console, but keep in mind that `System.out` will convert a `java.util.Date` to the whatever the time zone is of your JVM.

Comment: Sure. But still the times are off considering different time zones

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase and class names in PascalCase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime                             // Represent a date wih time-of-day but lacking he context of a time zone or offset.
.parse( "2010-01-01T00:43:54.776000" )    // Parse your standard ISO 8691 text with microseconds. Returns a `LocalDateTime` object. This is *not* a moment, *not* a point on the timeline.
.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )               // Apply an offset to determine a moment. Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object.
.toString()                               // Generate text in standard ISO 8691 format.
```

## *java.time*

Stop using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Always **search Stack Overflow thoroughly** before posting. All this has been covered many times already, so I’ll be brief.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2010-01-01T00:43:54.776000" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Generate text in the standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = odt.toString() ;
```

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to Java and didn't know that SimpleDateFormat was deemed to be terrible

Comment: In the ideal world newcomers to Java should have no chance of stumbling upon `SimpleDateFormat`. Unfortunately it is still mentioned in many places and without the warning that it is terrible and long outdated.